# Remove duplicate lines with a specific string from a file

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a file in which i have to remove the duplicate lines with same string at the last three positions

file.txt contains

`['aabbccj',  'biukghk',  'hgkfhff',  'hsgfccj', ' jflgsfs', 'fskfyhd',  'bfsbkhd',  'fjlfghk']`

i want the output as

`['aabbccj',  'biukghk',  'hgkfhff',  ' jflgsfs', 'fskfyhd',  'bfsbkhd']`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't see any duplicates in the file.txt list. Also please share what you have tried so far to solve it yourself.

Comment: i want to remove the second item in this list which has the common last 3 characters. like I have 2 items with ccj and ghk at the end of the words. I want to keep the first item with ccj and remove the second item

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a list of your endings. In your loop through the list, store them in a separate list and check for any new iteration:

```
list = ['aabbccj',  'biukghk',  'hgkfhff',  'hsgfccj', ' jflgsfs', 'fskfyhd',  'bfsbkhd',  'fjlfghk']
endings = []
results = []
for entry in list:
  if entry[-3:] in endings:
    # ending found, skip the rest
    continue

  results.append(entry)
  endings.append(entry[-3:])
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove elements which have last 3 characters, you can try this

```
my_list = ['aabbccj',  'biukghk',  'hgkfhff',  'hsgfccj', ' jflgsfs', 'fskfyhd',  'bfsbkhd',  'fjlfghk']
suffix = set()
output = []
for ele in my_list:
    #if common suffix detected skip the element
    if ele[-3:] in suffix:
        continue
    #else add suffix to set and append element to output
    else:
        suffix.add(ele[-3:])
        output.append(ele)
print(output)
#Output: ['aabbccj', 'biukghk', 'hgkfhff', ' jflgsfs', 'fskfyhd', 'bfsbkhd']
```

Comment: not a good idea to remove items from a list you are iterating over